# Does RegularExpressionValidator use other flavor than Regex?

Tags: .net, asp.net, regex, validation

I want to do preliminary check if entered string looks like [Vehicle Identification Number (VIN)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_identification_number). I know what it consists of 17 letters and digits, but letters I, O and Q are not allowed inside VIN, so I use this regular expression:

```
^[0-9A-Z-[IOQ]]{17}$
```

Now if I check a string like 1G1FP22PXS2100001 with RegularExpressionValidator it fails, but CustomValidator with this OnServerValidate event handler

```
Regex r = new Regex("^[0-9A-Z-[IOQ]]{17}$");
args.IsValid = r.IsMatch(TextBox1.Text);
```

works well.

Experiments show what RegularExpressionValidator doesn't support [Character Class Subtraction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms994330.aspx), but Regex class does.

Now I am interested why do these two .NET classes use different regex flavors? Is it documented somethere?

Comment: I just put the links directly in my answer instead of "hiding them" in the comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The RegularExpressionValidator also supports client-side validation using JavaScript, where the JavaScript Regex engine is used. The difference you see is the difference between the JavaScript and the .NET regex implementation.
You can disable client-side validation and thus force the validator to use the .NET regex engine, at the price of the additional post-back.

Answer (score 8):

Not a direct answer but just an obvious remark:

If for some reason Character class subtraction is not supported, you always can use as a workaround:

```
^[0-9A-HJ-NPR-Z]{17}$
```

---

To document what I put in the comments of this question:

The article **[How to: Validate Against Patterns for ASP.NET Server Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6xh899wy(VS.85).aspx)**, does mention that the javascript client-side regex validator does not know "character class subtraction"

As mentionned in **[RegularExpressionValidator Class .Net documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.regularexpressionvalidator.aspx)**:

> Both server-side and client-side validation are performed unless the browser does not support client-side validation or client-side validation is explicitly disabled (by setting the `EnableClientScript` property to false).
>
> The regular-expression validation implementation is slightly different on the client than on the server. On the client, JScript regular-expression syntax is used.
> On the server, `System.Text.RegularExpressions..::.Regex` syntax is used.
> **JScript regular expression syntax is a subset of `System.Text.RegularExpressions..::.Regex` syntax**.
> It is therefore recommended that **JScript regular-expression syntax should be used** in order to yield the same results on both the client and the server.

Another illustration of that side-effect (different regex flavors between server and client sides) is mentionned in [RegularExpressionValidator woes](http://weblogs.asp.net/cosgood/archive/2003/05/06/6604.aspx) blog entry.

Comment: IMHO, that's not the workaround, thats the only way to do it. I'm unaware that a thing like "character class subtraction" even exists. Or does it in some really weird regex flavor?

Comment: It does, since 2004, in .Net regex engine, but as pointed out by http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6xh899wy(VS.85).aspx, the javascript client-side regex validator does not know "character class subtraction"...

Comment: As mentionned in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.regularexpressionvalidator.aspx, on the client, JScript regular-expression syntax is used. On the server, System.Text.RegularExpressions..::.Regex syntax is used. => JScript regular-expression syntax should be used.

Comment: Another illustration of that side-effect (different regex flavors between server and client sides) is mentionned in http://weblogs.asp.net/cosgood/archive/2003/05/06/6604.aspx