# Aspx RegularExpressionValidator works differently on client and server

Tags: javascript, asp.net, regex, validation

I've got some problems getting a regular expression for the **RegularExpressionValidator** to work on the client:

```
(?=.{8,})(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[\d])(?=.*[\W])|(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[\d])(?=.*[\W])|(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[\W])|(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[\d])
```

This expression is supposed to return true if the supplied string

- consists of at least eight characters
- has at least one character in three of the four groups "lower case letters" / "upper case letters" / "digits" / "special characters"

Using this expression in C# (.NET 3.5) directly returns the expected results for different test strings, but within the client browser a valid string (e.g. aaaaBBB1) does not work.

I've read the [thread here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339763/does-regularexpressionvalidator-use-other-flavor-than-regex), so an explanation is the client side use of JavaScript which works slightly different compared to the .NET implementation.

Now I tried to run my regular expression in JavaScript to verify the arguments made in the thread linked above, but in JavaScript my regular expression also works the same as in C#.

Is there another way to get the RegularExpressionValidator working? I don't understand why JavaScript works (I expected it not to after reading about the implementation differences) but the RegularExpressionValidator doesn't.

Thanks in advance for any pointers into the right direction.

G.

Comment: For the special "\X" character classes (like "\d" and "\W"), there's no need to write them as "[\d]"; that's exactly the same as "\d" by itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
^(?:(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*\W)|(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*\W)|(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\W)|(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d)).{8,}$
```

Your regex would have allowed string of lengths under 8 to pass since the length assertion was only part of the first alternation.

Then (and this might be the problem) your regex never does match any text, it only does assertions. I have therefore taken the "length regex" outside the character restrictions and made it the actual match.

This should work both in JavaScript and in .NET.