# Regex subtraction not implemented in asp.net RegularExpressionValidator class?

Tags: c#, regex, subtraction

Is regex class subtraction not implemented in the ASP.NET RegularExpressionValidator class? I've been battling to get a fairly complicated regex to work, and have tracked it down to the fact that class subtraction doesn't seem to be implemented in the ASP.NET validator, but is in the Regex class.

For example: create a page with a text box and a validator for that text box. Give the validator the following ValidationExpression: [1-4][0-9-[5]]. No matter what input I put in, it doesn't match. Change it to [1-4][0-9] and it matches, but doesn't exclude 5 as the second digit, as required.

Thanks

Comment: I am getting a match on `11` when using `[1-4][0-9-[5]]`, and no match on `15`, `43` etc... The validator uses the normal .NET Regex engine.

Comment: What version of .NET framework are you using, Oded? BTW, 43 SHOULD match!

Comment: Whoops. Typo. That was supposed to be `63`...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does RegularExpressionValidator use other flavor than Regex?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/339763/does-regularexpressionvalidator-use-other-flavor-than-regex)

Answer (score 1):

The problem it seems is due to javascript regex being used (which can be turned off), see [regularexpressionvalidator-use-other-flavor-than-regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339763/does-regularexpressionvalidator-use-other-flavor-than-regex)

Read on for a suggested work around.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `[1-4]([0-4]|[6-9])` ?

Comment: I have, and that is my work around. Luckily I'm just trying to exclude a digit or two, and not a group of letters, etc. The example I gave is a pretty big simplification of what I am doing, but the idea is there. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you have a `|` in the character class? What you posted will match `2|`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @Oded. I've corrected the answer.

Comment: @VincePanuccio, no need for an alternation, just remove the `|` from the class, like this `[1-4][0-46-9]`